# Como hago para que me reconozca la propiedad .value de un objeto del DOM

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var texte = document.getElementById("texto_lineas");
var boton = document.getElementById("botoncito");
boton.addEventListener("click", dibujoPorClick );

var d = document.getElementById("dibujito");
var lienzo = d.getContext("2d");
var lineas = 30;
var l = 0;
var yi, xf;

for(l = 0; l < lineas; l++)
{
      yi = 10 * l;
      xf = 10 * (l + 1)
      dibujarLinea("red", 0, yi, xf, 300);
      console.log("linea " +  l);
}

dibujarLinea("red", 1,1,1,299)
dibujarLinea("red", 1,299,299,299)

function dibujarLinea(color, xinicial, yinicial, xfinal, yfinal)

{
lienzo.beginPath();
lienzo.strokeStyle = color;
lienzo.moveTo(xinicial, yinicial);
lienzo.lineTo(xfinal, yfinal);
lienzo.stroke();
lienzo.closePath();
}

function dibujoPorClick()
{
var p = texto.value;
alert("no me toques " + p);
}
```

No me reconoce la variable `p` que contiene `texto.value`. ¿que hago?

Comment: Tu problema esta en la declaración de la variable. La defines como `texte` y la usas como `texto`. En principio parece un error tipografico

Answer (score 1):

Buenas amigo espero esto sea lo que buscas saludos

1 - Tenias una variable mal declarada `texte` que llamas como `texto`

2 - le agregue una a la `function` `dibujoPorClick` el poder cambiar las lineas del canvas por las que le ingreses por el `input`

```js
var texto = document.getElementById("texto_lineas");
var boton = document.getElementById("botoncito");
boton.addEventListener("click", dibujoPorClick );

var d = document.getElementById("dibujito");
var lienzo = d.getContext("2d");
var lineas = 30;
var l = 0;
var yi, xf;

for(l = 0; l < lineas; l++)
{
      yi = 10 * l;
      xf = 10 * (l + 1)
      dibujarLinea("red", 0, yi, xf, 300);
      //console.log("linea " +  l);
}

dibujarLinea("red", 1,1,1,299)
dibujarLinea("red", 1,299,299,299)

function dibujarLinea(color, xinicial, yinicial, xfinal, yfinal)

{
lienzo.beginPath();
lienzo.strokeStyle = color;
lienzo.moveTo(xinicial, yinicial);
lienzo.lineTo(xfinal, yfinal);
lienzo.stroke();
lienzo.closePath();
}

function dibujoPorClick()
{
//var p = texto.value;
//alert("no me toques " + p);

var d = document.getElementById("dibujito");
var lienzo = d.getContext("2d");
var lineas = texto.value;
var l = 0;
var yi, xf;
d.width=d.width;
for(l = 0; l < lineas; l++)
{
      yi = 10 * l;
      xf = 10 * (l + 1)
      dibujarLinea("red", 0, yi, xf, 300);
      //console.log("linea " +  l);
}

dibujarLinea("red", 1,1,1,299)
dibujarLinea("red", 1,299,299,299)
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Numero de lineas" id="texto_lineas" type="text" name="" value="">
<button id="botoncito" type="button" name="button">Botoncito</button>

<canvas id="dibujito" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Okay amigo voy a mejorar la respuesta gracias por el dato

Comment: El error es tipográfico, en este caso hay que ayudar a los usuarios simplemente indicando el problema y cerrar la pregunta, saludos.

Comment: motivo de cierre : "Este problema contiene un error tipográfico."